# C strncpy 2 char

Tags: c, string, malloc, strncpy

I'm unable to make `strncpy` when I want to copy 2 chars from string, but same code is working when I want to copy 3 chars.

In this example, I need `strncpy()` to store 12 in 'to' variable:

```
void main(){
    const char* from = "12345678";
    char *to = (char*) malloc(3);
    strncpy(to, from, 2);

    printf("%s", to);
    free(to);
}
```

but when I use `strncpy(to, from, 3)` with `malloc(4)`, it works ok. Any solution to make this work?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Just read the doc: No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num.

Comment: Hint for the future: Don't use `strncpy`, most of the time it does not do what you want.

Comment: This bug is caused by using the dangerous `strncpy` function indeed. Never use that function, use `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead (together with appropriate buffer size checks).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to append the destination string with a terminating zero.

```
char *to = (char*) malloc(3);
strncpy(to, from, 2);
to[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: it works like that, thanks
well if I use malloc (3) and need 2 chars wont \n be added at the end of that array?

Comment: You do not need the cast in C